# Can try except improve the performance in Python

Tags: python, performance, try-catch

In python, if we want to check whether one element exists in a dictionary or not, `try` can be used like that,

```
try:
     mydict["condition"]
except:
     raise Exception("not exist")
```

Also, more elegant way to do that is defensive programming.

```
if "condition" in mydict:
     mydict["condition"]
else:
     raise Exception("not exist")
```

And, I think the `try exception` can cause software interruption, so the performance can be bad.
However, with the following test codes, it seems that `try except` can improve the performance.

```
import time

# count the executive time
def count_time(func):
    def wrap(*args):
        start = time.time()
        func(*args)
        end = time.time()
        print "func:%s  time:(%0.3f ms)" % (func.func_name, (end-start) * 1000)
    return wrap

@count_time
def exists_use_coarse_try(maxval):
    dict_list = {"something":"...."}
    try:
        for item in range(0, maxval):
            dict_list["something"]
    except:
        pass

@count_time
def not_use_try_fair(maxval):
    dict_list = {"something":"...."}
    for item in range(0, maxval):
        if "do_something" in dict_list :
            dict_list["something"]
        else:
            raise Exception("I know it exists!") 

def run(maxval):
    print "maxval:%s" % maxval
    exists_use_coarse_try(maxval)
    not_use_try_fair(maxval)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(10000000)
```

The result is

```
maxval:10000000
func:exists_use_coarse_try  time:(901.000 ms)
func:not_use_try_fair  time:(1121.000 ms)
```

My question is: Is the `try except` can improve the performance in Python?

Comment: "can cause software interruption" - what's "software interruption", and why would you expect it to hurt performance?

Comment: There's always `if my_dict.get('condition') is not None:`

Comment: if getting the value is your concern then use `get` method of `dict`